# Close <td> in a new row without adding a blank space character

Tags: html, html-table, indentation

I would like to indent my table cells like this:

```
<td>
    test
</td>
```

But when I highligth the cell content, it appears a blank space character after the text: in the example above, if I double click on the cell and copy the content, it copies `"test "`.

Two possible solutions are writing it in one line, like `<td>test</td>`, or trimming the cells content with jQuery, but I want to ask if anyone knows a better way to get rid of this white space.

Comment: The whitespace is coming from the newline at the end.  They are converted to spaces.  `test</td>` would get rid of the space, as would other methods.

Answer (score 1):

I've just created this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5wtap5w/)

Is this what you're looking to do? I added the css `display:inline-block;` to the `td` and it removes the white space after the text

Comment: jsFiddle doesn't add the white space, probably it has a bilt-in trim functionality for avoiding this behaviour. I'll try with some other text editor and update the question.

Comment: I've just tested the `display:inline-block` on both safari and firefox and for some reason it works to get rid of the extra space on safari, but not on firefox.. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cellspacing and cellpadding attribute

`<table cellspacing="0" cellpading="0">`